# Efficient way to implement Towers of Hanoi with steps returned as string

Tags: go, towers-of-hanoi

I'm comparing several algorithms in JS, Rust and Go. I implemented Towsers of Hanoi this way in Go:

```golang
func Hanoi() (hanoi func(n int, from, via, to string) string) {
    var moves strings.Builder
    var hanoiRe func(n int, from, via, to string)
    hanoiRe = func(n int, from, via, to string) {
        if n > 0 {
            hanoiRe(n-1, from, to, via)
            moves.WriteString(from)
            moves.WriteString("->")
            moves.WriteString(to)
            moves.WriteString("\n")
            hanoiRe(n-1, via, from, to)
        }
    }
    hanoi = func(n int, from, via, to string) string {
        hanoiRe(n, from, via, to)
        return moves.String()
    }
    return
}
```

But this implementation is much slower than JS or Rust. So I think, this could be done faster. But how?

I already tried `type hanoi struct{moves strings.Builder}` with `func (h *hanoi) ...`, which is a bit slower. The way using a string and `moves += ...`is much slower.

**EDIT:**

My comparisons:

**JS:**

```
class HanoiJS {
    constructor() {
        this.moves = "";
    }
    hanoi(n, from, via, to) {
        if (n > 0) {
            this.hanoi(n - 1, from, to, via);
            this.moves += from + "->" + to + "\n";
            this.hanoi(n - 1, via, from, to);
        }
        return this.moves;
    }
}
```

**Rust:**

```rust
pub struct Hanoi {
    moves: String
}

impl Hanoi {

    pub fn new() -> Hanoi {
        Hanoi {
            moves: String::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn hanoi(&mut self, n: i32, from: &str, via: &str, to: &str) -> &str {
        if n > 0 {
            self.hanoi(n - 1, from, to, via);
            self.moves.push_str(from);
            self.moves.push_str("->");
            self.moves.push_str(to);
            self.moves.push_str("\n");
            self.hanoi(n - 1, via, from, to);
        }
        return &self.moves;
    }
}
```

**Compared with n=20 and 5 times:**
[image: chart]

Comment: Write a benchmark and do the performance optimization. A starting point might be the (a bit outdated) article https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs. The main point is: write a func BenchmarkHanoi(b *testing.B) and run this benchmark, generating cpuprofile and memoryprofile (see go help testflag) and then anylze them via go tool pprof.

Comment: OK, I think I know where the time is taken. If I remove `moves.WriteString()` calls, it's much faster. But what is a more efficient way to build the string than using `string.Builder`? In Rust I'm using `String.push_str()` and in JS I simply add by `moves += "..."`.

Comment: Define a Steps struct with fields to and from. Pass in a slice of steps, append to it. Render the slice afterwards.

Comment: FYI: unrelated to your performance question, the closure function does not reset `moves` before beginning work. Therefore subsequent calls to this function will append to previous results still store in `moves`.

Comment: actually the above comment will may affect benchmarking - if one does not reset the moves string between benchmark invocations, then the string result will grow with each iteration (i.e. `hanoi(20, "A", "B", "C")` should always return the same result)

Comment: @colminator, Yes, In my test, it always gets reinstanciated (reseted). I also tryied it with a struct and a func implemenation (or say: a class). This was a little bit slower than the closure. It's really strange that Go is that much slower. I tested the fibonacci sequence too. And there Go is far slower too. Really strange.